# Jquery nested Add/Remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Can someone point me in the right direction to have add/remove functionality for top-level and sublists, that could produce a serialized output at the end?

Example:

Add Question

Question 1 | Delete

```
Answer 1 | Delete
Answer 2 | Delete
Add Answer
```

Question 2 | Delete

```
Answer 1 | Delete
Answer 2 | Delete
Add Answer
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/kgh68jgn/)

With this code you can understand the concept of how to make that .. use .remove() to remove elements but just make sure of selector.. and use .append to add data to element you want

in html :

```
<div class="ShowDivs">
   <div><a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a></div>
</div>
<a href="#" class="add">Add</a>
```

in css

```
.ShowDivs > div{
    background: yellow;
    margin: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.ShowDivs > div > a{
    float:right;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
```

in js

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    }).on('click','.delete',function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
    }).on('click','.add',function(){
        $('.ShowDivs').append('<div><a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a></div>');
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful. The part that I'm getting lost if the nested list portion. I assume that if I want to serialize this inforation later, I need to define each element with a specific name or id, how can I number depending on what currently exists?

Example:
<div class = "Question1"> Question 1 </div>

<div class = "ans1"> Answer 1 </div>
<div class = "ans2"> Answer 2 </div>

Add Answer

Comment: take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/tb1k776d/1/ just fill the field to get data for each row